# How to edit argument format

Tags: python, bash, arguments, sh, quotes

I have a python script...it gets called different then bash

```
./script.py 'arg1' 'arg2 stillarg2'
```

In the python script there is two arguments.

Now I want to call that with a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
./script.py ${1} ${2} ${3}
```

I want to call the bash script by in this syntax

```
./script.sh arg1 arg2 stillarg2
```

In the Bash script there is 3 arguments and no quotes.

So is there a way that by using a bash script, could call the python script with arguments. Without quotes and 3 arguments?.

I've Tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
./script.py "'${1}'" "'${2} ${3}'"
```

Outcome is:

```
operation not support
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to combine `$2` and `$3` in the same argument, no?

```
#!/bin/bash
./script.py "${1}" "${2} ${3}"
```